# Как добавить массив элементом к другому массиву (многомерные массивы)

Tags: php

Есть:

```
$families = array(array("Tom", "Alice"), array("Bob", "Kate"));
```

Нужно добавить массив элементом, чтобы было:

```
$families = array(array("Tom", "Alice"), array("Bob", "Kate"), array("Alex", "Bob"));
```

Comment: А читать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php) не пробовали?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией **[array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)** , которая добавляет один или несколько элементов в конец массива.

Можно такого же эффекта достигнуть такой конструкцией:

```
$arr[] = YOUR_CUSTOM_ARRAY
```

То есть написать имя массива куда будут складываться новые данные, дальше квадратные скобки и дальше присвоение